# Copy to clipboard buttons in browser no longer working

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, copy-paste, firefox

Starting yesterday, all of the sites I use frequently that have a "copy" button that copies text to my clipboard no longer work.

I can still highlight the text and cmd + c to copy, but would really like to know why the browser buttons are not working. This occurs in safari, firefox and chrome so it isn't browser related.

Running OSX 10.11.5
13in MBP retina

It is also a company computer, so please no solutions of erase and reinstall OS.

Comment: Did you update your software? Even a minor update to OS X could have done this. And you're not running Beta software, right?

Comment: Not running beta software, and have not updated it.

Comment: Really not sure about this. Do you have any common extensions between the browsers (an ad blocker, 1Password, Pocket, Avast, BitDefender, etc.) that could be modifying code (whether purposefully or not). Try disabling these. Note: the adblockers don't have to be the same brand/maker.

Comment: Nope, nothing in common because my only browser with extensions on this machine is Firefox. The only thing I have been doing out of the ordinary is installing/updating some ruby gems. And I know it isn't broken on the websites end because it works fine for my coworker.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to assume it's not the ruby gems (though I guess it might be) because I can't help you there. It seems like the copy to clipboard button is browser-based (it appears in Chrome on certain sites but not in Opera, for example). So let's do a test. Ensure your Chrome is up to date, turn off proxies/firewalls/similar things, and open up this link (in Chrome on your Mac): https://github.com/nasa/openmct. Press the big green `Clone or Download` button and you should see a link pop up, with a copy button next to that. Press it, and see if your clipboard changes. Then report back.

Comment: This worked in Chrome, as well as the site that I initially started having issues with. The github site worked in firefox, but the other site did not. And still didn't work in safari either. Did some digging in the plugins my coworker had installed in firefox and discovered it was because I did not have flash installed. They must have updated something on their backend making that a flash button for firefox and safari (or chrome has flash built into the browser). Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome; nice deductive work finding that answer, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some websites' 'copy to clipboard' buttons require Adobe Flash Player depending on your browser. Make sure flash is installed and up-to-date; see if that helps.